# Reading saved data from a file

Tags: android

I'm trying to read the data from a file that I've saved. This code is a part for reading the data "Value". But the compiler says there is an error at the last part 'return Value;'. It says 'Value cannot be resolved as a variable'. What should I do?

```
public static double[] getValue(){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("user_data.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

       double[] Value = (double[]) ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        try {
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare `Value` inside `try`, so it's not visible outside.  Try this instead:

```
public static double[] getValue(){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double[] Value;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("user_data.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        Value = (double[]) ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        try {
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Comment: It makes another error.. It says 'duplicate local variable value'.

Comment: @user1453296 Check my answer again: you need to remove the declaration inside the `try` block - only leave one `double[] ` - before the block.  Inside, just use the name of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `Value` variable outside the `try` block. Btw, use `value` as a name, instead of `Value`.

```
double[] Value;
try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("user_data.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

       Value = (double[]) ois.readObject();

    }
```

Comment: It makes another error.. It says 'duplicate local variable value'.